# Including a value once in a summed SSRS group

Tags: reporting-services

I have a data source which is pulling in event attendance information which looks like the following table.

Note that one booking can contain multiple attendees, causing duplication in the `Amount` column.

```
+------------+-----------+---------------+----------+
| Date       | Booking   | Booking Price | Attendee |
+------------+-----------+---------------+----------+
| 01/01/2011 | Booking 1 |       £300.00 | Alice    |
| 01/01/2011 | Booking 1 |       £300.00 | Bob      |
| 01/01/2011 | Booking 1 |       £300.00 | Dave     |
| 01/01/2011 | Booking 2 |       £200.00 | Frank    |
| 01/01/2011 | Booking 2 |       £200.00 | Julie    |
| 02/01/2011 | Booking 3 |       £100.00 | Anne     |
+------------+-----------+---------------+----------+
```

The Report *should* end up a bit like this:

```
+------------+-----------+---------+
| Date       | Booking   | Amount  |
+------------+-----------+---------+
| 01/01/2011 | Booking 1 |    £300 |
|            |    Alice  |         |
|            |    Bob    |         |
|            |    Dave   |         |
+------------+-----------+---------+
|            | Booking 2 |    £200 |
|            |    Frank  |         |
|            |    Julie  |         |
+============+===========+=========+
|   TOTAL FOR 01/01/2011 |    £500 |
|                                  |
|                                  |
+============+===========+=========+
| 02/01/2011 | Booking 3 |    £100 |
|            |     Anne  |         |
+============+===========+=========+
|   TOTAL FOR 02/01/2011 |    £100 |
|                                  |
|                                  |
+============+===========+=========+
```

(That pretty much exhausts my ascii-art table skills!)

The problem I have is that because the `amount` is showing for each delegate, the aggregate functions count them all, so date for 01/01/2011 shows as £1300, instead of £500

I don't need any values next to the attendees, so I could pull it in a separate data set, but I can't seem to add a table into a tablix cell, so don't know how that would work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The version of SSRS is key here. In SSRS 2008R2, you can now nest aggregate functions:

So this would now be a valid expression:

```
=SUM(FIRST(Fields!BookingPrice.Value , "BookingGroupName") , "DateGroupName")
```

If you aren't yet on 2008R2 then you can do some tricks with embedded code to keep a running total: http://beyondrelational.com/blogs/jason/archive/2010/07/03/aggregate-of-an-aggregate-function-in-ssrs.aspx

The key here is that you add to the total in the embedded code once per group. Then retrieve the total and clear it out at the end of the group.

Comment: I don't think we're R2, I'll have to check.  I remember doing similar to that other suggestion in Crystal Reports before - basically a sort of "if row=1 then add otherwise skip"

Comment: R2 added a lot of features for Reporting Services, and if you plan on doing much SSRS development, the upgrade is likely worth it. More feature additions/changes from 2008 to 2008R2 than there will be in 2008R2 to SQL Server 2012.

Comment: Great! Although I had to use the "Max" function instead of First. Unfortunately this doesn't seem to work with the Grand Total. Ideas?