# Formatting Group Total With Dynamic Column Name

Tags: reporting-services

What I want to accomplish:
1.Set the CaseNo column to for a new group to stand out in a separate line and same to follow for each detail until a new group is recorded.
2.Call the name of the column in a group total for that particular group

Currently, what I have produced is a bit different form the image below.
[image]

Comment: please refer to http://stackoverflow.com/a/7998197/3198474 that might help you

Answer (score 0):

I have got the fix!

= "Total Gap for " & Fields!CaseNo.Value & "  = " & Sum(Fields!Gap.Value)