# SSRS Group sum of unduplicated responses

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, ssrs-tablix

I am trying to sum a group of values in an SSRS report when another field is unique, but having trouble.

I have three connecting tables where the relationships are one (Organizations) to many (Activities) to one (Individuals). In my report, Organizations is the parent group and Individuals is the child group. I am trying to sum up a value in the Individuals table if it's connected to a value in the Organizations Table, but because there may be many records in the Activities Table that connect the Organization Table and the Individual Table, the first grouping isn't summing correctly. For example, if there are 3 Activity records for one Individual, and the value I want to sum (# Children, let's say 5), my report it is adding in 15 to the parent Group sum instead of 5. I would like to add in the values only once for each Individual record.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7997593/including-a-value-once-in-a-summed-ssrs-group

Comment: Do the grouping without the JOIN and then JOIN to that derived table, or use a subquery.

Answer (score 0):

How about a distinct within your count? So like `count(distinct IndividualID)`. Then it will only count distinct values found for each group instead of counting the total number of records.

Comment: That gets me part of the way, but if I want to sum a numeric value based on that unique value, then I'm stuck. The issue is that I'm not summing the same value that I'm looking to be distinct.

Comment: Make an inline query that gets you to your distinct data and then sum it. So lets say for one group by you have 3 individual distinct values but one of those has two records. The individual values are 1, 2, 2, and 3. And the values you want to sum for those matching values are 10, 50, 50, and 20. When you sum those values you would get 10, 100, and 20, right? But you want to get 10, 50, 20 (and then sum them). You need to get a distinct list first in the inline query and then sum it outside of that.

Comment: How would you write that out? I was thinking along those lines by adding a child grouping of individual, but I can't seem to get the parent group to sum the values in the child, it's still duplicating the activities.

Comment: Can you provide a mockup create and insert commands as well as the query as you currently have it?